# Kotlin - Do kotlin list filter creates a new list object?

Tags: java, kotlin, collections

```
fun main() {
  var list1 = listOf("AAAA", "ASAS", "ADDAD", "AS")
  var list2 = list1
  println(list2 === list1)
  list2 = list2
    .filter { it.length >= 3 }
  println(list2 === list1)
}
```

The output of above code is:

```
true
false
```

But I am confused why list1 is not being modified since both list1 and list2 are referencing to same list object first. Can anyone please help me understand what exactly is going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, `filter` does create a new list.

And when you do

```
list2 = list2
    .filter { it.length >= 3 }
```

you are assigning that new list to `list2`, so now `list2` stops referring to what `list1` refers to, and starts to refer to the list that was created by `filter` instead. Therefore, `list2` and `list1` now refers to different things.